# Content Of UITableviewcell need to repeat and maintain UITableviewcell Height Dynamic

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Here i have attached image in my UITableviewcell after UIButton (Show more). There are set of UIButton (btnCommentPic), UIButton (btnCommentName), UIlabel (tweetLabel), UIlabel (lblNotifyDate1)). I want to repeat this set many times means 2 times or 3 times and so on after show more. How can i achieve it? Guide me please.

Code link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzWEZWQllzLUZMdzA/view?usp=sharing

Expected Layout:-

[image]

Comment: use different type of table view cell for different type of layout and show in sequence. i can look into the code and i will update in some time

Comment: actually the project file is created in Xcode 8 and i am not able to open it. But my suggestion would be the same. Don't use multiple reusable layout inside single UITableViewCell. instead of this use different type of cells in a sequence. like one cell for blue box and one cell for the user info like name image and small description. and show those in a sequence or you can also use RATreeView and show the child elements of a parent cell like you planned.

Comment: @M.K. Thanks For response Bro
Here is the code in Xcode 7
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzSXlDZjQ1Y0xvOVk/view?usp=sharing

Plz guide me

Comment: @M.K I understand you want to say that I need to use Two layout. I did it same thing in other project like one cell for content and other cell is for load more UIButton

but here secnario is different  blue box is part of green box and sometimes I do not need blue box, i need only green box (according to requirement)
and Sometime i need to create many blue box like 1 ,2 blue box according to requirement and those all blue boxes are part of green box


SO Green Box + Blue Box = 1 UITableviewRow or 1 UITableviewCell